# How to replace a obsolete font tag with span using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

We need to migrate obsolete font tags generated in TinyMCE to new span tags in our CMS.

```
<font face="timesnewroman,times" size="7"><child>something</child></font>

<span style="font-family: timesnewroman,times; font-size: 12pt;"><child>something</child></span>
```

How do I do this using preferably using BeautifulSoup ? (Currently I am using 3.2.1 version)
Can you please tell me if there are any ways in Python to replace a font -> span tag with the style attribute set as mentioned? I do know few methods like replaceWithChildren but that wont do what I need . Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import BeautifulSoup as bp

soup = bp.BeautifulSoup('<font face="timesnewroman,times" size="7"><child>something</child></font>')


for t in soup.findAll('font'):

    t['style'] = 'font-family: %s; font-size: %s' % (t['face'], t['size'])

    del t['face']
    del t['size']
    t.name = 'span'

    print t
```

Output:

```
<span style="font-family: timesnewroman,times; font-size: 7"><child>something</child></span>
```

This is the basic idea. Obviously you should check if the attributes exist, or an exception will be raised.

Comment: Thank you . Exactly what I wanted , interesting it has a name property .